# convergence/divergence problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the following series absolutely converge, conditionally converge or diverge?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\sin(n^2)\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

I don't even know where to begin, I tried the limit comparison test with $b_n= 1/n^2$, but it does not work.

What should I do?

Comment: How do you conclude that "it doesn't work" ?

Comment: Are the limits on the sum correct now, after Jack's edit?

Comment: Limits are now correct yes.

Comment: $\sin(n^2)$ is bounded between $-1$ and $1$, $\sin\frac{1}{n^2}$ behaves like $\frac{1}{n^2}$ for large values of $n$, hence the given series is absolutely convergent. Nothing *tough* here.

Answer (score 0):

Comparison works !

$\frac{\sin(1/n^2)}{1/n^2} \to 1$ for $n \to \infty$. Hence there is $N$ such that

$\sin(1/n^2) \le 2/n^2$ for $n > N$.  Therefore

$|\sin(n^2)\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)| \le 2/n^2$ for $n > N$.

Comment: Ahhhh i forgot about the direct comparison test, thanks Fred! So the answer would be absolutely convergent right?

Comment: Yes, you are right !